# Code First Entity that doesn't include some required columns?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to use EF6 Code First to map Domain Entities to a legacy SQL database. I do not have access to modify the schema of the database or create stored procedures. The table I'm trying to map contains a few required columns that I don't want cluttering up my Domain Entities, since they aren't relevant to my program (but they're used by other programs).

The problem is that my program also needs to be able to add new rows to this table. I have a set of values I'm supposed to use for these extra columns when my program creates a new row (these values aren't database defaults but are specific for new rows coming from my program). I've been trying to use a `EntityTypeConfiguration` to map all the columns, but I can't find a way to set default creation values for unmapped columns.

Is there any way to make EF6 aware of these unmapped columns and set specific default values on `INSERT` (but not alter existing values on `UPDATE`)?

Comment: You can also use a command interceptor and modify the command (but private properties is more simple!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to map this columns in your model, you can't create default values if you don't map these properties. What you can do is set this properties as private in your model and the map with Entity framework as is described in this blog http://romiller.com/2013/01/23/ef6-code-first-mapping-all-private-properties-using-custom-conventions/ using reflection.

Comment: +1 Actually, [the other article](http://romiller.com/2012/10/01/mapping-to-private-properties-with-code-first/) referred to inside your linked article seems to be the most helpful one.  Mapping private properties is definitely the right way to do this.  Also, to answer the other part of OP's question, you can set default values by initializing the private properties in the entity's constructor.